# how to generate rules from csv files in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm not familiar with Prolog, but I need help generating rules from CSV data using attribute value pairs.

I tried to generate rules from the table below, but it was difficult for me.

```
obj height hair eyes class
o1  short  blond blue  c1
o2  short blond brown c2
o3  tall   red     blue     c1
.
.
.etc.
```

I tried to find the first rule about C1, calculate all the `p(C1|av)` for all attribute value pairs, then delete covered objects from set, repeating these steps for each class.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but I think you are trying to read a TSV (tab-seperated?) file and produce clauses based on the values.

For example, the following TSV file...

```
ID    a1    a2
o1    abc   def
o2    bcd   efg
```

...represents the facts...

```
a1(o1, abc)
a1(o2, bcd)
a2(o1, def)
a2(o2, efg)
```

The following program will read a tab-delimited file and produce a list of such clauses. Here is my input file...

```
id  height  hair    eyes    class
o1  short   blond   blue    c1
o2  short   blond   brown   c2
o3  tall    red blue    c1
```

The following code will read a file in this format (object ID is expected to be the first column) and produce the clauses...

```
% Exmaple clause to read a file and print out facts to the console.
% Instead of printing, you could do whatever you like with them (assert them into WM for example)
example :-
    build_facts_from_file('c:\\tmp\\data.tsv', FACTS),
    writeln(FACTS).

% build_facts_from_file(FILENAME_IN, FACTS_OUT).
% Reads the file and outputs a list of facts.
build_facts_from_file(FILENAME, FACTS) :-
    open(FILENAME, read,S),
    read_tsv(S,[HEADER | RECORDS]),
    close(S),
    build_records(HEADER, RECORDS, FACTS).

% read_tsv(INPUT_STREAM_IN, LINES_OUT)
% Read tab-seperated values from the stream S into a list (one element per line)
read_tsv(S, []) :-
    % Stop if EOF
    at_end_of_stream(S), !.

read_tsv(S, [L | T]) :-
    % Read whole line as character codes
    read_line_to_codes(S, CODES),
    % Translate the line into a list of atoms
    translate_tsv(CODES, [], L),
    % Read the other lines
    read_tsv(S, T).

% translate(CHARACTER_CODE_LIST_IN, ATOM_SO_FAR_IN, ATOMS_OUT).
% Gets a line, splits it on TAB characters and turns each element into an atom
translate_tsv([], [], []) :- !. 
    % Stopping condition when tab was at end of line, but no extra element  
translate_tsv([], ATOM_CHARS, [ATOM]) :-
    % Stopping condition when non-tab was at end of line, 
    % turn list of codes for the atom found so far into an atom
    atom_chars(ATOM, ATOM_CHARS).
translate_tsv([9 | CODES], ATOM_CHARS, [ATOM | ATOMS]) :- !,
    % Tab found, turn ATOM_CHARS into ATOM and start building the next atom
    atom_chars(ATOM, ATOM_CHARS),
    translate_tsv(CODES, [], ATOMS).
translate_tsv([CODE | CODES], ATOM_CHARS, ATOMS) :- !,  
    % Non-tab character found, appent CODE to the end of ATOM_CHARS and keep going
    append(ATOM_CHARS, [CODE], TMP_ATOM_CHARS),
    translate_tsv(CODES, TMP_ATOM_CHARS, ATOMS).

% build_records(HEADER_IN, RECORDS_IN, FACTS_OUT)
% Process each element in RECORDS_IN to create FACTS_OUT
build_records(_, [], []).
    % Stopping case, no records left to build
build_records(HEADER, [RECORD | RECORDS], FACTS) :-
    % Build facts for all the other records
    build_records(HEADER, RECORDS, FTMP1),
    % Build facts for this record
    build_fact(HEADER, RECORD, FTMP2),
    % Add lists together
    append(FTMP1, FTMP2, FACTS).

% build_fact(HEADER_IN, ATTRIBUTES_IN, FACTS_OUT)   
% Builds clauses for each attribute - strips out the object ID (assumed to be first attribute)
% and calls build_fact/4 to do the work
build_fact([_ | HEADER], [ID | ATTRIBUTES], FACTS) :-
    build_fact(ID, HEADER, ATTRIBUTES, FACTS).

% build_fact(OBJECT_ID_IN, PROPERTY_NAMES_IN, VALUES_IN, FACTS_OUT) 
build_fact(ID, [PROP | PROPS], [VALUE | VALUES], [FACT | FACTS]) :-
    % create term for the fact
    FACT =.. [PROP, ID, VALUE],
    % build the rest
    build_fact(ID, PROPS, VALUES, FACTS).

build_fact(_, [], [], []).
    % Stopping condition
```

Example output:

```
1 ?- example.
[height(o3,tall),hair(o3,red),eyes(o3,blue),class(o3,c1),height(o2,short),hair(o2,blond),eyes(o2,brown),class(o2,c2),height(o1,short),hair(o1,blond),eyes(o1,blue),class(o1,c1)]
```

Hope this helps